# How do I maximally separate n points in a cube in Python? How do I use scipy.integrate.ode?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, ode

I need to find n points in the unit cube that roughly maximizes their separation.  I am currently looking at writing this problem as an ODE and using `scipy.integrate.ode` to do the work.  That is, doing a simulation whereby each of the particles repel each other along with the walls of the cube.  I don't care too much about efficiency.

Unfortunately I can't get it to work for problems bigger than n=5:

```
import numpy as np


def spread_points_in_cube(n, dimensions=3, rng=None):
    from scipy.integrate import ode
    if rng is None:
        rng = np.random

    size = n * dimensions
    y0 = np.zeros((2 * size))
    y0[:size] = rng.uniform(size=size)
    t0 = 0.0

    def clip_to_wall(positions, forces):
        forces = np.where(positions == 0.0,
                          np.clip(forces, 0, np.inf),
                          forces)
        forces = np.where(positions == 1.0,
                          np.clip(forces, -np.inf, 0.0),
                          forces)
        return forces

    def decode(y):
        positions = np.clip(y[:size].reshape((n, dimensions)), 0, 1)
        velocities = clip_to_wall(positions, y[size:].reshape((n, dimensions)))
        return positions, velocities

    def f(t, y):
        retval = np.zeros((2 * size))
        positions, velocities = decode(y)
        #print("pos", positions)
        delta_positions = positions[:, np.newaxis, :] - positions[np.newaxis, :, :]
        # print("delta_positions", delta_positions)
        distances = np.linalg.norm(delta_positions, axis=2, ord=2)
        distances += 1e-5
        # print("distances", distances)
        pairwise_forces = delta_positions * (distances ** -3)[:, :, np.newaxis]
        # print("pairwise f", pairwise_forces[0, 1])
        forces = np.sum(pairwise_forces, axis=1)
        forces -= 0.9 * velocities
        forces = clip_to_wall(positions, forces)
        #print("forces", forces)
        retval[:size] = velocities.reshape(size)
        retval[size:] = forces.reshape(size)
        return retval

    r = ode(f).set_integrator('vode', method='adams')
    r.set_initial_value(y0, t0)
    t_max = 40000
    dt = 1
    while r.successful() and r.t < t_max:
        r.integrate(r.t + dt)
    return decode(r.y)[0]
```

Comment: @LutzL: Friction added as per your suggestion.  Still doesn't work though :(

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean?  Be specific.  Did you get an error?  An output that you didn't expect? In the latter case, show the output that you got, and explain what you expected.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser: Thanks for taking a look.  It doesn't converge.  You can paste the code in yourself if you want to try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Poisson Disk Sampling is a linear time algorithm to do this.  References: http://devmag.org.za/2009/05/03/poisson-disk-sampling/, http://bost.ocks.org/mike/algorithms/,

Bridson, Robert. "Fast Poisson disk sampling in arbitrary dimensions." ACM SIGGRAPH. Vol. 2007. 2007.